# running two identical docker-compose containers on the same server

Tags: docker

I've run into a problem. There is a microservice, its docker-compose:

```
version: "3.3"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: traefik

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: test
    command: sh -c "uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 7778"
    restart: always
    links:
      - db_test
      - worker_test
      - beat_test
      - rabbitmq_test
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/code/app
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.subdomain=test"
      - "traefik.http.services.test.loadbalancer.server.port=7778"
      - "traefik.http.routers.test.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"

    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db_test

  db_test:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db-test
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: docker
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  worker_test:
    build: .
    container_name: merge_duplicates_worker-test
    restart: always
    command: ./app/worker.sh
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq_test

  beat_test:
    build: .
    container_name: beat-test
    command: ./app/beat.sh
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq_test

  rabbitmq_test:
    container_name: rabbitmq-test
    restart: always
    image: "rabbitmq:3.10.5"
```

When I start everything works fine as it should, now I change the port for traefik, traefik.subdomain, container names, etc. and I start the second container, it works without errors, but the problem is that data from the first container of its database is pulled into the new container into the database. Links does not affect this in any way, I tried to delete it, it did not affect it in any way.

Comment: Is the database volume being shared between the two database containers?

Comment: path volumes remains the same, should it be set new?

Comment: If the path volume remains the same and you're running it from the same directory, then both containers will share the same underlying data. Postgres will write all its data (files for tables, metadata, etc) in that shared volume, so both postgres processes will access the same files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have separate DBs with separate data, you need to change the volume of the DB-Container! Something like this:

```yaml
db_test:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db-test
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: docker
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres2:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Notice the `./data/postgres2` part. Also running two instances of PostgreSQL on the same data directory sounds dangerous and may lead to data loss.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. the postgres2 folder is created but the data is still pulled from the other database

Comment: Okay, can you check that your web-app is really communicating with the right DB? You should probably switch from using links to networks as links are a deprecated feature. I am not sure, what happens, if you have 2 containers with the same name, as links rely on container names to route traffic

Comment: now I'm running without links

Comment: If you put the two instances on separate networks, does it work?

Comment: I don't know, I definitely need to use the traefic network

Comment: also they have the same postgres addresses and when i try to change the postgres address in the second container i get an error "Temporary failure in name resolution"

Comment: Have you also changed the container name of the second DB? DNS resolution in docker containers also relies on container names.

Comment: yes, names are different